# How can I get the results to be paged like almost all web pages do in radphp?

Tags: database, controls, radphp, rpcl

Experimenting with no success on the dbpaginator component included with radphp xe2, I wonder how can I manage to page records displayed on the dbrepeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the **Pager** component instead, which is also supported in **HTML5 Builder**.